# Can a UK citizen with permanent residence in an EU country work remotely for a company based in a different EU country?

Tags: eu, working, brexit, eu-settlement-scheme

As far as I understand it, post-Brexit EU residency granted to a UK citizen allows them permanent residence and right to work in their chosen country.

They don't have the right of freedom of movement and cannot simply go and work in another country as they could before Brexit.

However, can they work remotely (ie. remain resident in their original chosen country) for a company based in a different EU country?

I can't see why this would be a problem (income tax would be paid in the country of residence as usual) but neither can I find any information which definitively states one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A residence permit issued based on the withdrawal agreement (Aufenthaltsdokuments-GB, **Artikel 50 EVU**) includes an **unrestricted** work permit, based on the non-discrimination of existing rights to equal treatment portion of the withdrawal agreement (Article 12).

So the field **TYPE OF PERMIT** should contain the text: **ARTIKEL 50 EVU** as shown in the image:

[image]

---

This does not apply to UK citizens who have taken up residence since 2021-01-01, where the normal 3rd country rules apply.

---

**Sources**:

- [Anwendungshinweise zur Umsetzung des Austrittsabkommens Vereinigtes Königsreich - Europäische Union, 2020-11-06, Version 1.1](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/downloads/EN/news/anwendungshinweise-brexit-en.pdf) (PDF)

  - Point 8.5.2. (page 41)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have such a card, with the Article 50 text on it. What I'm wondering is whether I'm allowed to work _remotely_ for a company which is _outside_ my country of residence, while I remain inside my country of residence.

Comment: @AaronF You are **physically** working in Germany,  that is what counts. You have already noticed that you must tax and health insurance for the same reasons.

Comment: @AaronF For taxes, that might not always be true depending on any existing double tax agreements.

Comment: Thanks again! (I'm actually in Spain, though that distinction probably doesn't matter in this case)  I'll leave the question the customary 24 hours before accepting your answer :-)

Comment: @AaronF Sorry, for some reason I thought it was Germany. That makes the pdf source rather senseless. You should then check the Spanish implementation, since this may differ in the area of the work permit. It **may** be German specific that independent of the time spent previously, the work permit is unrestricted - which normally is only granted after 5 years residence. Will adapt the answer.

Comment: My Spanish residence permit is permanent and I can work freely anywhere in Spain, that much is clear. What isn't stated anywhere (on the many different Spanish government websites) is whether I can work for a company that's foreign but within the EU. All that I can assume right now is that I would have the same rights as a Spanish citizen in this instance: if the company I want to work for doesn't have a presence in Spain then I register myself as self-employed and invoice the foreign company.

Comment: @AaronF Yes, I agree. As long as you have permission to work in Spain, the government will have no objection in receiving taxes from your earnings.

Comment: Ignoring double taxation, you need the right to work in the country where your body is, and you need to pay income tax in the country where your body is. The other country _may_ want taxes from you, and then double taxation agreements would come into play. Being self-employed may be easier, because say an Italian company wouldn't be interested in having to learn about Spanish tax and employment laws, which they need to know if you work from Spain. Self employed, they just get a bill and pay it, with some details about VAT.